# T-SQL Handling No Results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to retrieve information about servers in our environment and some of the servers that I need to retrieve information for do not exist. For example, ServerD, ServerF, ServerJ, and ServerN are not in the table I am querying.

```
SELECT Server, Active, Location
    FROM Repository.dbo.Servers
    WHERE Server IN (
    'ServerA',
    'ServerB',
    'ServerC',
    'ServerD',
    'ServerE',
    'ServerF',
    'ServerG',
    'ServerH',
    'ServerI',
    'ServerJ',
    'ServerK',
    'ServerL',
    'ServerM',
    'ServerN',
    'ServerO'
    )
    ORDER BY ServerName
```

These are the results of this query, but I'd like some kind of value for the Servers that do not exists (ServerD, ServerF, ServerJ, and ServerN), such as NULL, etc.

```
ServerA N   Springfield, IL
ServerB Y   Cleveland, OH
ServerC Y   Springfield, IL
ServerE Y   Cleveland, OH
ServerG Y   Cleveland, OH
ServerH Y   Memphis, TN
ServerI Y   Springfield, IL
ServerK N   Cleveland, OH
ServerL Y   Cleveland, OH
ServerM Y   Springfield, IL
ServerO Y   Memphis, TN
```

How can can this be done in T-SQL? For example, I would want something returned similar to this:

```
    ServerA N   Springfield, IL
    ServerB Y   Cleveland, OH
    ServerC Y   Springfield, IL
    ServerD NULL
    ServerE Y   Cleveland, OH
    ServerF NULL
    ServerG Y   Cleveland, OH
    ServerH Y   Memphis, TN
    ServerI Y   Springfield, IL
    ServerJ NULL
    ServerK N   Cleveland, OH
    ServerL Y   Cleveland, OH
    ServerM Y   Springfield, IL
    ServerN NULL
    ServerO Y   Memphis, TN
```

Comment: Do you have some table where all the servers do exist?

Comment: Is your question how to detect whether a SQL Server instance exists? And further, how to do that in T-SQL?

Comment: We have a separate table where all the servers exist, but that table does not have the information I need. And I'm looking for some kind of data to come back for ServerD, ServerF, ServerJ, and ServerN. Since no data was detected for those server, nothing is returned at all in the results. I'd like some value to be returned for those rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comments you have some table that does have all the servers. Use that table and left join the servers table.

```
SELECT t1.Server, t2.Active, t2.Location
FROM TheTableThatHasAllServers t1
LEFT JOIN Repository.dbo.Servers t2 on t1.server = t2.server
WHERE t1.Server IN (
'ServerA',
'ServerB',
'ServerC',
'ServerD',
'ServerE',
'ServerF',
'ServerG',
'ServerH',
'ServerI',
'ServerJ',
'ServerK',
'ServerL',
'ServerM',
'ServerN',
'ServerO'
)
ORDER BY t1.ServerName
```